# Developing peg plan software for textile application

Tags: c#, sql, user-controls, desktop-application

I am developing a desktop textile program with c#(win forms) and ms-sql. I need to create a dynamic created editor for planning peg.

It should let user to reverse cell colour by clicking on it and let user to add-remowe rows or columns.

And I want to save data in a string in database (e.g. 1,1 ; 1,3 ; 2,2 ; 3,1 ; 3,3 ; 4,2 ; 5,2
)

What kind of control do I need to use for creating such editor?

[image: example peg plan on excell]

Comment: Your own one. I doubt anyone would have created what you are looking for, although a grid is probably a good start! What are you using to write your application (WinForms / WPF)?

Comment: I use WinForms and yes I made a start with grid. just I wondered is it a good idea to use grid for such solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my problem as below;

```
        //button creates datagrid as desired dimension
    private void btKenarRaporOlustur_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        KenarRaporuOlustur((int)nudKenarKolonAdet.Value, (int)nudKenarSatirAdet.Value);
    }

    //gird creator
    private void KenarRaporuOlustur(int columns, int rows)
    {//           
        var dtKenar = new DataTable();

        for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++)
        {
            dtKenar.Columns.Add(j.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        {
            dtKenar.Rows.Add();
        }

        dataGridView1.DataSource = dtKenar;

        foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in dataGridView1.Columns)
        {
            column.SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable;
        }

        foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in dataGridView1.Columns)
        {
            col.Width = 25;
        }

        dataGridView1.RowHeadersVisible = false;

        dataGridView1.AllowUserToResizeRows = false;
        dataGridView1.AllowUserToResizeColumns = false;
    }

    //grid mouse click event
    private void dataGridView1_CellMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.RowIndex < 0 || e.ColumnIndex < 0) return;
        var cell = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex];

        cell.Selected = false;
        cell.Style.BackColor = cell.Style.BackColor == Color.Black ? Color.White : Color.Black;

        cell.Value = cell.Value.ToString() == "1" ? null : "1";
    }
```